# Update the authorities in the Authentication object once the user is authenticated and before authorizing him for an endpoint

Tags: spring, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security, authorization

I have a situation where i have to authorize the user to certain path (endpoint) depending on the role he has.
Problem: Once the user is authenticated, i see an empty set of authorities in authentication object (which is used by authorizing filter to determine access for the user.)

I am new to spring security and would need help to address this.

Background: We have a authorization server implemented in the organization which uses oauth2 and lets us do the single sign on. SSO happens in the front end which gets the token from the authorization server and embeds it to every request sent to my server. Now my server decodes the token and authenticates the user. the user claim doesn't have authorities information and i am not allowed to make any code changes in my authorization server..

What i am looking for : Once the user gets authenticated and before he proceeds for authorization (i am using filters in my web security config) i want to make a call to the DB and get the user respective roles and save it to my authentication object, so that the authorities are now updated, user will be authorized to the endpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `SecurityService` and call it from `@PreAuthorize` annotation

```
@GetMapping()
@PreAuthorize("securityService.hasRole('ADMIN', authentication.principal.username)")
public String getData() {
  return "response";
}
```

And call authorized server from SecurityService with rest template for example:

```
public class SecurityService {

  public boolean hasRole(String role, String username) {
    String role = restTemplate.getRoleByUserName...;
    // check role 
    return false/true
  } 
}
```